# Delegate method didUpdateLocations is called after trying to use data that has not yet been retrieved from itself - Xcode Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have an NS object (called GoogleSearch) that I use to get the user's location data. These are some global variables created and the init function:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D?

override init() {
    super.init()
    print("1")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

}
```

Next, here is my delegate method:

```
extension GoogleSearch: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print("2")
    let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
    self.coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
}
}
```

Next, I try to access the coordinates (set in the delegate method) in a later function:

```
func searchForPlaces(completion: @escaping ([place])->()) {
    print(coordinates)
}
```

Finally, in the **ViewController** that I implement this **NSobject**, I have the following code in viewDidLoad:

```
self.googleSearch = GoogleSearch()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.googleSearch.searchForPlaces(completion: { (places) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.places = places
                self.placesCollectionView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }
```

The problem is that printing coordinates in the searchForPlaces functions prints nil because it is run before the delegate method is called. Is there anything I should change in my NSObject or perhaps my ViewController to ensure that I can access coordinates from searchForPlaces() ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve in this way:

```
class GoogleSearch:NSObject {

  let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
  var coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
  var completionHandler: ((CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Void)?

  override init() {
      super.init()
      print("1")

    }

   func searchForPlaces(completion: @escaping (CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Void) {
     self.completionHandler = completion
     self.locationManager.delegate = self
     self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
     if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
     }
   }
}


extension GoogleSearch: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
     print("2")
     let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
     self.coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
     self.completionHandler?(self.coordinates!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Unfortunately, it did not work for me. I believe you might need to add in the completionHandler somewhere? @Shubham

Comment: Where is your  `searchForPlaces`  is declared?

Comment: Oops. I added the wrong one above, see my edited answer. It is called in a VC in the viewDidLoad func. @ Shubham

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work either. I need searchForPlaces to have a completion handler of type Place as shown above. And, I need to access coordinates IN searchForPlaces. What could I do from here? Thanky you for all the help. @Shubham

Comment: If you need completion handler of the type of `Place`, then what is the issue in that, just change the type.

Comment: One second. I appreciate the help, I will look into this tomorrow.

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean. Let me rephrase the question. I want searchForPlace to return a Place. The problem is that it is called before I set my global variable, coordinates, in didUpdateLocations. So when I print coordinates it prints nil. I do not understand why this is happening because in my viewDidLoad function in the ViewController that uses the NSObject, GoogleSearch, it is initialized first, which means that the delegate method should be called, THEN it should print coordinates in searchForPlace. But this does not happen. Thanks again for your help.